# Windows Server 2008: How do I configure a scheduled task to run with the logged on user's permissions?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, scheduled-task

On Windows Server 2008 R2, with User Account Control enabled, I want to run Process Explorer (as Administrator) when I log in.  Though I have administrative rights on the server, I am not the only person using it, nor am I authorized to do anything I want, especially if it may interfere with other people.  To avoid the annoying and process delaying UAC popup when starting Process Explorer, I've discovered that I can use the Task scheduler to run it with full permissions.

However, I use multiple accounts when logging onto that server and I want it to run with full permissions at log on with each of my accounts (and no one else's account).  I do not see any option in the task configuration to use the logged-in account for the task's security context.  Is this possible?  If so, how do I configure the task?

Answer (score 0):

I think to achieve this, you need to do it with groups, rather than individual users. For example, the Server Manager task, which causes the Server Manager to appear on start up, is configured like this:

[image: Server Manager Task]

In particular, using the "Administrators" group, and configured to "Run only when user is logged on". So, for your case, simply create a group called "ProcessExplorerUsers" or whatever and assign that as the user of your task.

I presume you've already found the "At Log On" Trigger.

Comment: Yes, I've already found the "At Log On" trigger.  :)

Comment: However, I only have it running at log-on for just one of my accounts.  I'll experiment a bit with groups and hope that the server/network group doesn't mind...